# Generating data from elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, testing, automated-tests

I have a lot of elasticsearch queries but I don't have any data in my database.

I would like to populate some random data in elasticsearch if the query I run returns no result, so as to make the query return some non-empty result. This is for test purposes.

What would be the best approach for implementing this?

(I'm using the Elasticsearch Java client)

Comment: did you get a chance to look into my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any Out of the box solution, as you know your domain and search queries, its best to have a data-set according to your requirements indexed in Elasticsearch before you run your tests, so that it never returns the empty search results.